# Ho To Set default value from db to select taghelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, select, set, default

I have select tag helper in each row of table. Value for the attributes gets from database. I can see value from db assigned to attribute but in view it always show first value of enumerate. My View is :

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ListQueues)
                {
                    <tr class="noPadding">
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.caseId)</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patientId)</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mobilePhone)</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.payment_status)</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.doctor)</td>
                        <td>
                            <select asp-for="@Model.patientData.appointment_status"
                                asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<eNumAppointmentStatus>()"
                                onchange="myFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)"
                                class="form-control selectpicker" data_width="auto" ,
                                data_live_search="true"></select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <button data-row="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)" class="clsActionButton"
                                style="text-align:center;background-color:#0b5ed7;color:white;">
                                Get Details
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

At controller I can see value of appointment_status as 3 (Prescribed). But it always show 1 (YestToArrive)

My enumerate is :

```
 public enum eNumAppointmentStatus
{
    [Display(Name = "Yet To Arrive")]
    YetToArrive,
    [Display(Name = "Arrived")]
    Arrived,
    [Display(Name = "InRoom")]
    InRoom,
    [Display(Name = "Prescribed")]
    Prescribed,
    [Display(Name = "Discharged")]
    Discharged
}
```

How can it set value from database.